# Pasar datos de textbox en USERCONTROL a Datagridview en otro USERCONTROL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

ESTOY TRABAJANDO CON USERCONTROL POR PRIMERA VEZ.
MI CASO ES:
Tengo 2 **USERCONTROL** en un Formulario (**FORM1**), donde el **USERCONTROL1** contiene varios Textbox y un segundo **USERCONTROL2** que contiene un datagridview.
Si me pueden ayudar con el caso, como puedo pasar los datos de los textbox al datagridview.
Y si se puede cargar los datos del datagridview a los Texbox al seleccionar una fila del datagridview. Gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentando de varias forma y no he tenido ningún resultado, esto es lo ultimo que he intentado en el
FORM1

```
namespace Proyecto
```

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  
}

private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1 UC1= new UserControl1 ();
    UserControl2 UC2= new UserControl2 ();

    UC1.Tag = UC2;
    UC2.Tag = UC1;
}
```

}

USERCONTROL1

```
public partial class USERCONTROL1: UserControl
```

{

```
internal class Persona
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    public double Precio { get; set; }
}

public USERCONTROL1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

internal Persona CurentPersona
{
    get
    {
        return new Persona()
        {
            Nombre = txtNombre.Text,
            Precio = txtPrecio.Text,
        };
    }
    set
    {
        txtNombre.Text = value == null ? string.Empty : value.Nombre;
        txtPrecio.Text = value == null ? string.Empty : value.Precio;
    }
}

private void btnEntrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

USERCONTROL2

```
public USERCONTROL2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void USERCONTROL2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgvContenido.Rows.Add("Limon", "10");
    dgvContenido.Rows.Add("Naranja", "20");
    dgvContenido.Rows.Add("Guineo", "22");
}

private void dgvContenido_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = (DataGridView)sender;
    if (grid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name != "EditColumn") return;

    var rowToEdit = grid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    var dialog = new DialogForm
    {
        CurentPersona = new Persona()
        {
            Nombre = (string)rowToEdit.Cells["NombreColumn"].Value,
            Precio = (double)rowToEdit.Cells["PrecioColumn"].Value,
        }
    };

    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        rowToEdit.Cells["NombreColumn"].Value = dialog.CurentPersona.Nombre;
        rowToEdit.Cells["PrecioColumn"].Value = dialog.CurentPersona.Precio;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes mandarle de parametro al usercontrol1 el usercontrol2, en cuyo caso siempre tendras acceso a todo el usercontrol1 desde el usercontrol2

```
   class UserControl1
    {
       UserControl2 Controltextboxes;
       UserControl1(UserControl2 controltextboxes)
       {
          Controltextboxes = controltextboxes;
       }
       void funcion()
       {
          string cadena1=Controltextboxes.TextBox1.Text;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda @Ulises B pero en verdad no me ha funcionado